# Change text of button by the amount of times it has been clicked

Tags: javascript, html, button, text, repeat

For a practice test I am asked to find a way to make a button reveal text in a paragraph. Each time it is pressed, the text must change.

For the first time pressed the button should say "you pressed the button"
second "you pressed it again
third to fifth time "you pressed the button (a number from 3 to 5) times"
and sixth and onward it should say "stop!"

EDIT EDIT EDIT

This is the entire Original HTML, i am not sure if it is needed, but maybe the html could have something to do with the javascript codes you all have given me to not work for me.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="q2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="go()">ClickMe</button>

<p id="output">
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function go() {
    var out = document.getElementById("output");
    var x = "hi there";
    out.innerHTML = x;
}
```

What should I do to make this work?

Comment: Hi @Mirthi, welcome to [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). I hope we were able answer your question, if so, please accept an answer or let us know if you need more assistance...

Comment: @WhiteHat Thank you very much! this is a great site, i didnt expect to get an answer honestly but i was honestly surprised and filled with relief once i saw so many people were willing to help, thank you guys!

Comment: You need quote marks around btn1 (id="btn1")

Comment: @realseanp Yes after reading your comment, i did quote it realizing my dumb mistake, but even then it did not work

Comment: Why dont you update your question to show all of the code you are using

Answer (score 2):

use a `switch` statement to avoid nested `if` statements...

```
var testCount = 0;
var out = document.getElementById("output");

function go(){
  testCount++;
  switch (testCount) {
    case 1:
      out.innerHTML = 'you pressed the button';
      break;

    case 2:
      out.innerHTML = 'you pressed it again';
      break;

    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
      out.innerHTML = 'you pressed the button ' + testCount + ' times';
      break;

    default:
      out.innerHTML = 'stop!!';
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought about doing a switch as well, but I think using the condition >1 && <= 6 would be better than writing duplicate switch statements for 2, 3, 4, and 6. Seems to be cleaner.

Comment: Patato Potato, @realseanp you are splitting hairs at this point.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith i guess it would come down to cleaner code.

Comment: @realseanp well then, WhiteHat's code is a bit "cleaner" then yours, he has more options with less coding, what exactly is your point? or are you just trolling?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I guess it just comes down to opinion then .. in your opinion the switch statement is cleaner than what i did. all i'm saying is that the switch statement rubs me the wrong way... And i'm not sure why you down-voted my answer

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith why would I upvote this answer? its not the way i would do it.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith who's trolling now

Comment: And I like that there's no reason as to why the down votes were given

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith yeah go ahead just do me a favor and leave a reason why you did it :) i'm always looking to improve my coding skills

Comment: hey guys, we're here to help the OP, `switch` evaluates once, it's better than multiple `if` statements

Comment: Thank you for helping me out @WhiteHat, unfortunately the code doesnt work for some reason. this isnt the first time my javascript would not work. I am new to computer coding and programming so I don't know whether the program im using (atom within a Virtual machine called Virtualbox, I verify the javascript by opening it in the firefox within VM) or there is somethign wrong with the code? when I click the button it only shows the first button click msg, if i click it again and again, nothing will happen.

Comment: you should edit your question to show the code you have now. sounds like scope, make sure your counter variable is declared outside of your counter function `go`, as in the example. otherwise, the counter value will be set to the same thing with every click.

Comment: @WhiteHat I do not know how, but the 5th time I copied and pasted your code it worked :/ idk what happened though lol which means i have to study it and see why it works XD. thank you so much! I may get a 90 or above on the comming test afterall! thank you alot

Answer (score 0):

Or how about this one?

```
'use strict';

let count = 0;

// define this outside of function so it won't be defined over and over
let out = document.getElementById('output');

let message;

function go(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    count ++;
    out.innerHTML = count > 1 ? count === 2 ? 'You pressed the button again!' : count > 1 && count < 6 ? `You pressed the button ${count} times!` : 'Stop!' : 'You pressed the button';
}

// It's best practice to stay away from inline JS, you could define your click handler in your script block
// For the following to work add id="btn1" to your button and remove the onclick handler

document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', go);
```

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith how about this one ?

Comment: if js perfed this one too, if statement seems fastest between switch, ternary, and if.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out! But unfortunately, just like the code above yours, it doesnt seem to work. I changed my button to be:

    <button id=btn1 type="button">ClickMe</button>

is this the right code you asked me to change the button to? Sorry if I am wrong, i am new to this whole programming thing

Comment: @Mirthi Here friend check this pen out: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQEJEX you can see the HTML and then the javascript. If you have your code in an HTML file make sure you dont have any syntax errors and put your javascript after your HTML

Comment: @Mirthi do you want to post your code the exact way you have it ? then maybe we can tell you what the problem is. If it is the way you have mentioned in the comment above you will need quotes around id=btn1

Comment: Yes i posted the entire original code, would you like me to post the code I had with your javascript with it? I put a link to the JAVASCRIPT into the HTML in the head section. thats how my prof is telling me to do it.

Comment: @Mirthi you said you put it in the head? You will need to put it below your button and message markup, unless you put it within a window onload function. But its better practice to put your JS at the bottom of the markup right about the closing body tag. This way any blocking JS won't hang things up

Answer (score -2):

You could do this:

```
'use strict';

let count = 0;

// define this outside of function so it won't be defined over and over
let out = document.getElementById('output');

let message;

function go(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    count ++;
    if(count === 1) message = 'You pressed the button!';
    if(count === 2) message = 'You pressed the button again';
    if(count > 1 && count < 6) message = `You pressed the button ${count} times!`;
    if(count >= 6) message = 'Stop!';
    out.innerHTML = message;
}

// It's best practice to stay away from inline JS, you could define your click handler in your script block
// For the following to work add id="btn1" to your button and remove the onclick handler

document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', go);
```

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith what's so overkill about it?

Comment: I guess it just comes down to opinion then .. in your opinion the if statement is cleaner than what i did. all i'm saying is that the if statement rubs me the wrong way... And i'm not sure why you down-voted my answer... lol

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith comparing an if statement to a switch in this case the if statement is actually on average 14% faster not that anyone would be able to tell the difference but its still faster

Comment: Thank you again for the help @realseanp, but it seems all the codes I have been given by all of you dont seem to work. I have no idea why they do not work though.

Comment: @mirthi: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33138274/change-text-to-everytime-i-click/33138812#33138812     Check the jsfiddle there

Comment: @santon LOL I think the person that posted this question goes to my university, same practise answers XD thank you so much for the link!