# change text to everytime I click

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

So I want to do this, and I'm fairly new to JavaScript:

1. The first time the button is pushed, the text should be changed to "You pushed the button." (no quotes).
2. The second time the button is pushed, the text should be changed to "You pushed the button (again)." (no quotes).
3. The third through fifth times the button is pressed, the text should be changed to "You pushed the button [n] times." (no quotes). [n] should be replaced by the number of times the button has been pressed.
4. If then button is pressed six or more times, the text should be replaced with "Stop pushing the button." (no quotes).

This is what I currently have:

```
function go() {
    // alert("alert!");
    var paragraph = document.getElementById("output");
    paragraph.innerHTML = "You pushed the button";
}

function go2() {
    var paragraph2 = document.getElementById("output")
    paragraph2.innerHTML = "You pushed the button (again)";
}
```

THE HTML IS HERE : https://gyazo.com/8f24747521b539e2a68058716126279f

any helps :( please someone??

Comment: the first part works where i press the button it shows you pushed the button but then when i press it again it doesnt show the second message

Comment: you're writing javascript not java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change text of button by the amount of times it has been clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091270/change-text-of-button-by-the-amount-of-times-it-has-been-clicked)

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091270/change-text-of-button-by-the-amount-of-times-it-has-been-clicked?noredirect=1#comment54000848_33091270

Comment: @realseanp but the other one isnt answer, and its not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like this:

JS

```
    var clicks = 0;
 function onClick() {
   clicks += 1;
   var message = "";
   if(clicks==1)
     { message = "You pushed the button.";}
   else if(clicks==2)
   {message ="You pushed the button (again).";}
    else if(clicks >= 6) //for 6 clicks and above
   {message ="Stop pushing the button.";}
   else
     {message = "You pushed the button " + clicks + " times.";}
   document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = message;

 };
```

html:

```
     <button type="button" id="buttonclick" onClick="onClick()">Click me</button>
<div id="message"></div>
```

example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaEExW

Comment: i get this but how do i do the other ones , so every time i click button it changes text and how do i add this one to that

Comment: @Alundra: Still incorrect. correct code to clicks>= 6

Comment: @santon nice catch. fixed that

Comment: 1 more question , what would u do if u wanted the text to change color at 7th key

Comment: @kashyap why don't you put a bit of effort from your end for your homework

Comment: @kashyap you can do the rest yourself and it's really not that hard and you will feel great about it

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/santon/mc15vy4f/)

Create a simple click tracker object which counts user clicks. I have added a getMessage to this tracker to provide the correct message based on what the click count is.

```js
var myBtn = document.getElementById("myButton");

var clickTracker = {
count: 0,
getMessage: function () {
    var message;

    switch (this.count) {
        case 1:
            message = "You pushed the button";
            break;
        case 2:
            message = "You pushed the button (again).";
            break;
        case 3:
            //fall Through
        case 4:
            //fall Through
        case 5:
            //fall Through
            message = "You pushed the button " + this.count + " times.";
            break;
        default:
            message = "Stop pushing the button"
    }
    return message;
}
};


function processClick() {
   clickTracker.count++;
   document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = clickTracker.getMessage();
}

myBtn.addEventListener("click", processClick);
```

```html
<button id="myButton">Click Me</button>
<p id="message"></p>
```

Comment: yea but i dont want it on the button i want it as a text below the button , the button should say click me only and it should display text below it

Comment: @Kashyap: added to a paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to keep track of how many times the button was clicked:

```
var clicks = 0;
```

You can use an array as a list of strings for changing the button text:

```
var buttonText = [
    "Push the button.",
    "You pushed the button.",
    "You pushed the button again.",
    "You pushed the button 3 times.",
    "You pushed the button 4 times.",
    "You pushed the button 5 times.",
    "Stop pushing the button."
];
```

You can access the items from the array by index. The index number is the same as how many times the button was clicked:

```
buttonText[0]; // Push the button.
buttonText[4]; // You pushed the button 4 times.
buttonText[clicks];
```

Here is the full JavaScript code:

```
var clicks = 0;
var button = document.getElementById("myButton"); // You can change this.
var buttonText = [
    "Push the button.",
    "You pushed the button.",
    "You pushed the button again.",
    "You pushed the button 3 times.",
    "You pushed the button 4 times.",
    "You pushed the button 5 times.",
    "Stop pushing the button."
];
function buttonClicked() {
   clicks += 1;
   button.innerHTML = buttonText[clicks];
}
button.addEventListener("click", buttonClicked);
```